Flutter How to display virtual keyboard when a barcode scanner is connected
I want to use a bluetooth barcode scanner to automatically fill the fields in my flutter app. The problem is that it prevents a system keyboard from appearing when scanner is paired with a device. I have two fields: one to scan barcode and second to input some text, and I can not type anything in the second field because keyboard isn't showing. Is there a way to force system keyboard to appear?

https://pub.dev/packages/virtual_keyboard_multi_language you can use this virtual keyboard as a work around.

Isn't there an option to use both ?
